# Event Panel Component Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

[image: Waterfall timeline like component]

Are there ready-made solutions for such a component in Angular?

It resembles the waterfall in the browser's inspector.
But I cannot find any solutions because I do not know what it is called. Has anyone worked with such components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build such things easily with angular. Here is a "minimal" example.

First the little `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, WaterfallComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <app-waterfall [requests]="sampleRequests"></app-waterfall>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  sampleRequests: NetworkRequest[] = [
    { name: 'Request 1', startTime: 0, endTime: 100 },
    { name: 'Request 2', startTime: 50, endTime: 150 },
    // ... more requests
  ];
}
```

NetworkRequest Interface:

```
export  interface NetworkRequest {
  name: string;
  startTime: number; // In Millisekunden
  endTime: number;   // In Millisekunden
}
```

The **waterfall.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-waterfall',
  templateUrl: './waterfall.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./waterfall.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true
})
export class WaterfallComponent {
  @Input() requests: NetworkRequest[] = [];
}
```

its **HTML**

```
<div class="waterfall-container">
  <div class="axis">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let number of [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]">
      <div class="axis-label" [style.left.px]="number">{{ number }}</div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <div class="waterfall">
    <div *ngFor="let request of requests" class="request" 
         [style.width.px]="request.endTime - request.startTime" 
         [style.marginLeft.px]="request.startTime">
      {{ request.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

a little **CSS**

```
.waterfall-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.axis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.axis-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.waterfall {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.request {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

And the result:

[image]

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sehswd?file=src%2Fwaterfall%2Fwaterfall.component.css) is the Stackblitz.